# Which hash/encryption type is used by Kali Linux for /etc/shadow by default?

Tags: hash, kali-linux, sha

I know that the `/etc/shadow` file hash follows this syntax:
`$id$salt$encrypted`

The `$id` identifies the algorithm being used, e.g.:

- `$0` - DES
- `$1` - MD5
- `$2a` - Blowfish
- `$5` - SHA-256
- `$6` - SHA-512

Here is an entry of my shadow file:

`root:$6$89Zi5dxn$RvKDsJQhBiX2K3CEVUE3nQxvdBV.3vDK4Jrn11xC8jO31c43VnZeTL1OGaJWfFkl9di8nfreAXFLreCuQDshf1:16234:0:99999:7:::`

I'm running the most up-to-date Kali Linux version (for 2014), which is based on Debian "wheezy", which in turn uses SHA-512, hence `$6`.

The problem I am having is that I went to an online service, which calculates and "reverse-calculates" SHA hashes and input my password ("root") there. The hash they showed me did not match the hash in my `/etc/shadow`-file, and when I entered my hash from the file to search against their database, they claimed the format was invalid.

I know that using a salt would affect the hash in some way, but as far as I can tell, my hash does not use a salt, as it follows the format `$id$hash`, not `$id$salt$hash`.

As such, I would like to ask the following:

- Why does my hash not look like a "normal" SHA-512 hash?
- What kind of hash is this, if it is not "normal" SHA-512?
- Can I recognize the type of hash by only looking at the `$id`?

Comment: There is clearly a salt in the shadow entry.

Answer (score 4):

The site you linked to calculates plain SHAs and outputs in hex, not salted SHAs with multiple rounds output in base64, so it's basically impossible to compare them.

In your shadow entry, splitting on `$` you have `6`, which is type SHA512, `89Zi5dxn`, which is the salt, and then `RvKDsJQhBiX2K3CEVUE3nQxvdBV.3vDK4Jrn11xC8jO31c43VnZeTL1OGaJWfFkl9di8nfreAXFLreCuQDshf1`, which is a base64-encoded hash.

In addition to the salting, libc applies a number of rounds of the hash, defaulting to 5000.  If you want the details on how a crypt() style SHA512 is calculated, here's a link to the source: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/sha512-crypt.c